# Unable to find element while using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

This is html where I want click on particular image

```html
<img id="td1" title="OP &amp; ER" runat="server" class="image-responsive" src="../App_Themes/Images/Icons/Sidebar New Icons/OP-ER.png">
```

I tried Xpath : `html/body/form/div[3]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/img"`

Xpath : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[3]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/img")).click();`

Unable to locate element error message.

Comment: @uma, Did you check for iframes? If iframes are present try switching to the frame and then try with any locator strategies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with find by id as given below.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("td1")).click();
```

if id of the image is dynamic try with the following xpath to identify it.

```
//img[@src='../App_Themes/Images/Icons/Sidebar New Icons/OP-ER.png']
```

Some times clicking on anchor tag may work then img tag

```
//img[@src='../App_Themes/Images/Icons/Sidebar New Icons/OP-ER.png']/../a
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("td1")).click(); tried but not working. Actual html is img id="td1" title="OP &amp; ER" runat="server" class="image-responsive" src="../App_Themes/Images/Icons/Sidebar New Icons/OP-ER.png"

Comment: if non of the above methods are working, then try with javascript executor.

Answer (score 0):

img id="td1" title="OP & ER" runat="server" class="image-responsive" src="../App_Themes/Images/Icons/Sidebar New Icons/OP-ER.png"  this is the html

I tried driver.findElement(By.id("td1")).click(); but not working.

Comment: Unable to locate element: #td1

Comment: is the id dynamic or constant?

Comment: Id is constant one.

Comment: then it should not through error element not found. try with x-path //img[@src='../App_Themes/Images/Icons/Sidebar New Icons/OP-ER.png']

Comment: Unable to locate element: //img[@src='../App_Themes/Images/Icons/Sidebar New Icons/OP-ER.png']

Comment: is it dropdown list/sub menu?

Comment: It is Sub menu.

Comment: may be your sub menu available only after clicking on main menu or mouse over on main menu. please try click/mouse over on main menu then try to click on submenu

Comment: Before sub menu we are having div- Wrapper, div- Sidebar-wrapper, div- tblMainMenu, a - div1, img - td1